# Execute R Script from Web Application with Java

Tags: java, r, rscript

I have created a Web Application with Struts, and I would like to execute and R script from a Java class.

My script is in the directory: WebContent/script
The name is: rScript.R

I have checked that a way to execute is using this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("WebContent/script/rScript.R")
```

But this doesn't work. Does someone know how I have to put the sentence?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to call the executable program that runs script not just the script itself: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RScript WebContent/script/rScript.R")`

Comment: thanks for the response, but the result is the next one `Cannot run program "RScript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`
Do I have to put something on the script?

Comment: On unix (Linux/Mac) machines it is case sensitive for *Rscript* and you may not have it as an environment variable. If, not try: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/full/path/to/Rscript /full/path/to/WebContent/script/rScript.R")`

Comment: I don't really know what is the direction of Rscript.  Is it the same path of my Script?

Comment: It is an executable program, Rscript.exe, residing in your R bin directory along with Rterm.exe, Rgui.exe, R.exe. Every command line needs the executable program that runs it. Your script is just an argument to it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Now I do not have compile error, but it seems that is not doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Process process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RScript C:/.../WebContent/script/rScript.R")
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the result of your comand is this: `Cannot run program "WebContent/script/rScript.R": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: If full path has any spaces/special chars, wrap in escaped double quotes within `exec` string.